# jQuery's .hide() doesn't set style="display: none;" consistently across browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

**Background:**
I am using `QUnit` to validate the creation of `DOM` elements in the following manner (which has been working fine so far):

```
$actual = Mylibrary.createSomething();
$expected = $('<div........');
ok($actual[0].isEqualNode($expected[0]),'Node properly created');
```

More info on `isEqualNode`: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.isEqualNode), [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-isEqualNode)

**Issue:**
I am having an issue comparing nodes when I use the `jQuery's .hide()` method because:

- it produces `style="display: none;"` (no extra space after `;`) with `Firefox`
- it produces `style="display: none; "` (extra space after `;`) with `Chrome`
- `isEqualNode` considers that `style="display: none;"` is different than `style="display: none; "` (you can have attributes in different order and `isEqualNode` still considers nodes to be equal, but that extra space not).
- when building `$expected`, I can only cater for 1 of the 2 situations.

Accordingly my tests end up always failing with `Chrome` or `Firefox` depending on which situation I choose to create `$expected`.

Here is a [jsFiddle so that you can see what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/Xd7X4/3/)

I could check if element is hidden with `.is(':hidden')` but that isn't ideal to me because:

- I can no longer compare whole set of DOM elements with `.isEqualNode` like I currently do and would have to write many individual tests to get an equivalent which will make my tests very extensive and hard to maintain.
- I feel that by using a `DOM` method (i.e. `isEqualNode`) my tests are more robusts than if I used a `jQuery` method (e.g. `.is(':hidden')`) because my elements are generated with `jQuery` in the first place and having a `jQuery`-independent verification method will more likely spot problems.

**Do you see the discrepancies with the way the `jQuery`'s `.hide()` method generates the `stype="display` attribute as a bug/problem? (i.e. should I raise it on http://bugs.jquery.com/)?**

**Do  you see a solution that would allow me comparing my nodes without using `jQuery` methods?**

Comment: Afaik, jQuery just uses `el.style.display` - so you need to blame the browser for generating the html string

Comment: How are you defining equality between two nodes that are inherently not equal? They aren't both referencing the same object, and they've got different parents, children, and siblings. String equality is a bad approach as `<div id="foo" class="bar"></div>` is the same as `<div class="bar" id="foo"></div>`

Comment: @zzzzBov: `isEqualNode` compares the node and its children (not its parents nor siblings) and won't care if attributes are not in the same order on each node as long as they have the same value which is exactly what I need to validate my code because I generate some elements programatically, create some manually, and use `isEqualNode` to compare them, and if browsers happen to insert the attributes in different order it won't break my test. The only issue I'm having is that extra space after `display: none;` :(

Comment: But `<div class="foo bar"></div>` and `<div class="bar foo"></div>` describe the same thing as well, so it sounds like you need to add some extra logic to how attributes are compared.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Indeed, I think ultimately I would need to write my own function :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From QUnit perspective perform the following check in order to see whether the element is hidden:

```
equal(element.css('display'), 'none', 'element is not hidden');
```

This eliminates the need for you to compare string differences. If you are not using jQuery then perform:

```
equal(element.style.display, 'none', 'element is not hidden');
```

If you would like to create some utility extensions to modularize your unit/interaction testing, then isEqualNode is not your best approach here. Better provide yourself with methods like:

```
checkClass(element, cssClass)
checkAttribute(element, attr, value)
checkAttributeExists(element, attr)
etc...
```

Comment: I think creating my own functions is going to be necessary (another problem highlighted above is that `.isEqualNode` will think `class="foo bar"` is different than `class="bar foo"` (which it is from a `DOM` standpoint, although functionally it's the same, I think as long as rules from 1 class don't overwrite rules from the other).

Comment: @user359650 Yes that is why the implementation of your checkClass utility should not rely on reading all of the classes but rather one checking one class at a time.